# Probability of knowing the source of a sound after hearing it

Tags: probability

I am given this problem by my professor and I can't figure a reasonable answer, though I know it'll be easy.

Suppose to hear a sound on your roof at midnight. It could've been a thief or an animal, respectively with probability

$$ P(S \mid X=\text{thief})= 0.8, \quad P(S \mid X=\text{animal})=0.3 $$

We know that $P(X=\text{thief})=0.001$.

We want to find the probability of the sound to have been caused by a thief after hearing that sound, so it should be $P(X=\text{thief}\mid S)$ (I think).

No other clue is given, I have tried to solve it via Bayes' Theorem, putting

$$P(X=\text{thief}\mid S)= \frac{P(S\mid X=\text{thief})\cdot P(X=\text{thief})}{P(S)}$$

but this is assuming $P(S)=1$, because you did hear a sound. Moreover, this would mean that the result will be $0.8\cdot 0.001= 0.008$, which seems counter-intuitive. The text of the problem is unclear, I know, but it's all I've got.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct up to guessing $P(S)=1$. The probability of hearing a sound is given by the probability of hearing a sound and $X$ being a thief added to the probability of hearing a sound and $X$ being an animal. Hence we have
$$P(S)=0.001\times0.8+(1-0.001)\times0.3=0.3005$$

Comment: what is the general formula that you've used? i have a feeling that i'm missing a basic of probability calculations..

Comment: All I've used is that for statistically independent events $A$, $B$ we have that $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)=P(A|B)\times P(B)$$Here you need $P(S)=P((S\cap \text{theif})\cup(S\cap\text{animal}))=P(S\cap \text{theif})+P(S\cap\text{animal})$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint to compute P(S):**

$$ P(S) =P(S,X=\text{thief})+P(S,X=\text{animal})$$

Comment: but that would give me 1.1, which is impossibile

Comment: How? Please show your calculations. It is not conditional probability, it is joint probability

Comment: $P(S|X=thief)$ is 0.8, $P(S|X=animal)$ is 0.3, added together gives 1.1

Comment: $$P(S,X=\text{thief})=P(S|X=\text{thief})P(X=\text{thief})$$ Can you proceed now?